# Eulerian Trail proof in Walk Through Combinatorics

Tags: graph-theory

I'm struggling with the proof of Eulerian trail in walk through combinatorics.
As you now, the theorem states that "A connected graph G has a closed Eulerian trail if and only if all vertices of G have even degree."

I'll only ask <- part. Book gives an algorithm how to construct an Eulerian trail actually.

1. Step:
   Take any vertex S, and start walking along an edge e1, to the other endpoint A1 of that edge, then walk along any new edge e2 that starts in A1. Continue this way, using new (previously unused) edges at each step, until a closed trail C1 is formed. The first closed trail will be formed when we first revisit a vertex already visited.
2. Step:
   If C1 = G, then we are done. If not, then choose a vertex V in C1 so that C1 does not contain all edges adjacent to V.
3. Step:
   Let us now remove all edges of C1 from G. We get a graph in which again all vertices have even degree. Starting at V , let us take another closed trail C2 in the remaining graph. We can then unite C1 and C2 into one closed trail in G. Indeed, if we start walking by C1, we can stop at V , walk through C2, then complete our trail by using the remaining part of C1.

Now my question is that in the algorithm when we start constructing our first C1 it does not guarantee that C1 includes the starting point S. Now again for C2 it does not actually guarantee that it includes vertex V. Then how can we union C1 and C2 ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathoverflow. You question is more appropriate for math.stackexchange. That said, there's indeed an inaccuracy in this description of the algorithm: in the first step, you need to continue as long as you can, i.e., until you arrive at a vertex and find out that all incident edges are used, rather than until you form a closed loop. This way, the end vertex can only be the starting one.